# Pulling in specific elements with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am building a Wordpress site.  I am using Ajax to pull in content from another page to fill an empty div when a particular element is clicked. Each element has a different URL so I made the Url a variable.  I need Ajax to only pull in a particular element from this URL.  Instead it keep pulling in the entire page. I've tried using various methods to select the specific element, but I've hit a wall and need a little help.

```js
    (function($) {

        function find_page_number( element ) {
            return parseInt( element.html() );
        }

        $('.member-info').on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            page = find_page_number( $(this).clone() );

            var memberSrc = $(this).attr('href');

            $.ajax({

                url: memberSrc,
                type: 'get',
                dataType:'html',
                data: {
                    action: 'ajax_pagination',
                    query_vars: ajaxpagination.query_vars,
                    page: page
                },
                success: function( html ) {
                    $("#main").empty();
                    $('#main').append( html);
                }

            });

        })
    })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the answer with jQuery:

```
$('#main').append( $(html).find('#main').html() );
```